# A question from S. Weinberg's book (Sec. 2.7)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, symmetry, group-theory

S. Weinberg in his book "The quantum theory of fields" page 82 says: the elements $T,\bar{T}$, etc, of the symmetry group may be represented on the physical Hilbert space by unitary operators $U(T),U(\bar{T})$, etc. (by Wigner's theorem) which satisfy the composition rule $$U(T)U(\bar{T})=\exp \big( i\phi (T,\bar{T})\big) U(T\bar{T}),\quad (*)$$ with $\phi$ a real phase.  When either $\bar{T}$ or $T$ is the identity, the phase $\phi$ must clearly vanish $$\phi (T,1)=\phi (1,\bar{T})=0.$$

But why?

My try: By the relation $(*)$, we have $U(T)U(1)=\exp \big( i\phi (T,1)\big) U(T)=U(T)\exp \big( i\phi (T,1)\big) $. Since $U(T)$ is unitary, it is invertible, so $U(1)=\exp \big( i\phi (T,1)\big)$. But why $\phi (T,1)=0$? $U(1)$ represents the symmetry element $1$ (by Wigner's theorem) in the symmetry group $\{ f:PH\to PH\}$ which $f$ is bijective function that preserves the probobility, i.e., $[\Psi]=1[\Psi]=[U(1)\Psi]$ for all $[\Psi] \in PH$, the projective space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $\phi(T,1)$ is independent of $T$. Let $\phi(T,1)=\phi_0$. You can rescale your unitary operators by a constant phase ${\tilde U}(T) = e^{-i\phi_0} U(T)$. The new set of unitary operators satisfy ${\tilde U}(1) = I$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. could you please tell me why $\phi (T,1)$ is independent of $T$?

Comment: Because you got $U(1) = e^{i \phi (T,1)}$. The LHS is independent of $T$ so the RHS must also be.

Comment: I got it. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with representing a group element by an operator on hilbert space. But, when we are representing elements of a group by linear transformations on a vector space, it must be that the identity element of the group must be represented by the identity transformation on the vector space. If same is applicable here, we can say that

$U(e) = \mathbb{I} $

Where $e$ is the identity element in the group and $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity operator on the hilbert space. Applying this to the equation * in your question,  we get the desired constraint on $\phi$.